# The contents of the div element in SVG cannot be displayed, and it is normal to modify the div tag in chrome's console to be the body

Tags: html, svg

The contents of the div element in SVG cannot be displayed, and it is normal to modify the div tag in chrome's console to be the body

```html
<svg id="path-canvas" width="1591" height="623">
   <g class="zoom-container" width="1591" height="623">
     <g class="edgegroup"></g>
     <g class="nodegroup">
       <g class="node" id="node-aaav_dept_eedafae__0" transform="translate(136,174)" cx="136" cy="174">
          <rect class="rect" width="200" height="100" rx="5" ry="5" style="fill: rgb(202, 255, 255);"></rect>
          <foreignObject class="foreign-object" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100">
             <div class="container" style="border:1px green solid">dsf的是非得失了</div>
          </foreignObject>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g class="drawgroup"></g>
    </g>
 </svg>
```

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you mean by "*it is normal to modify the div tag in chrome's console to be the body*", but your SVG element appears to display perfectly fine with the above code.

Comment: So-called in chrome console to modify div tags are normal mean directly change the div tags to the body tag, the text inside can shows, other foreignObject if without div inside, just plain text can also be shown correctly,thank you